# Android/Java slow network IO

Tags: java, android, performance, httpurlconnection

I have an app in which I am trying to download a file. I am using `HTTPUrlConnection` for the download. Initially download speeds were way to slow.

I improved the performance by using a buffered input stream and increasing my buffer size from 1024 to 8192. Increasing the buffer beyond that did not lead to any improvement.

Here is a snippet :

```
InputStream inputStream = (InputStream) new URL(requestURL)
                    .getContent();
BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(
                    inputStream);
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileSaveUrl);
BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    outputStream);    

int bytesToRead = 1024 * 256;
byte buffer[] = new byte[bytesToRead];
while ((count = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1
    && !isCancelled()) {
        requestStatus((int) (downloaded * 100 / fileSize));
        bufferedOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Even after this, the same file downloads 2 times quicker on the iPad when compared to Android.

Am I missing something?

**Edits**

1. Even before you ask/mention , the download is running on a separate thread.
   I do realize I do not need to buffer the output , but I will get around to that later :)
2. About the `bytesToRead` : I was experimenting with different buffer sizes , last experiment was 256KB

Comment: Have you tried how much speed-up you get by disabling writing the data to disk?

Comment: I would, but Android has limited heap sized provided to Apps & the files could be larger than the provided heap size , thus I directly write it to the SD Card. Also I did run a few tests, the writing to file section is not slowing down the entire program.

Comment: "Also I did run a few tests, the writing to file section is not slowing down the entire program" -- it should be. Usually in multithreaded programming, you write on a different thread than you read if you are aiming for maximum performance.

Comment: I basically used a bunch of print statements & printed time taken,  while it did take up sometime it was negligible to the time taken to read from the steam , that is the section I am trying to speedup. I will implement your suggestion and get back to you.

Comment: @Ravi: And make sure you are writing only full 4k blocks or multiple of it (AFAIR sd-cards are organized by 4k, internal flash memory may have larger blocks). Flash is extremely slow when writing smaller blocks because of the process read (unchanged data of an block) - erase (full block) - write (full block).

Comment: @Robert Great point, will follow up soon

Comment: @Robert, I did a few tests, looks like SD card is the culprit. Time to put some hungry Philosophers to work :)

Comment: @CommonsWare you were right :) , to be frank I did not expect it to be such a huge bottleneck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that I was downloading and writing to the SD card on the same thread. Split the work into two threads using a Blocking queue buffer to improve the performance.

Answer (score 2):

```
requestStatus((int) (downloaded * 100 / fileSize));
```

This could be one possible bottleneck. Updating a status in the same thread your doing work usually isn't a good idea. Your thread should be updating a volatile variable...

```
variable = (int) (downloaded * 100 / fileSize);
```

Then your UI thread should poll that variable to show progress.

Also, most cheap SD Cards are slow, writing to them will likely cause a slow down for large files.